# Logout is just clearing cookies

Tags: cookies, session-management

My friend who is a web developer implemented his session management in a totally new way for me.

He created a random `sessionAPPID` that is given to the user when he gives correct credentials.

He then created a HTTP header that has this form:

```
APPID: sessionAPPID 79299291724
```

He stores the sessionAPPID in the backend and verifies it on every request. At this point everything is normal apart from the fact that he could have used bearers instead of creating a custom HTTP header.

What seems weird for me is that he stores the sessionAPPID in the cookie:

```
cookie: sessionAPPID=79299291724
```

He does not even compare his sessionAPPID in the custom header to the one in the cookie (verification with the one in the backend only).

When a user needs to logout he just clears his local cookie and does not delete it from the backend. When the user log in again he is given another random `sessionAPPID`.

I told him to just clear the `sessionAPPID` from the backend but he said it useless because there is an expiration date.

I told him that if an attacker steals the cookie it is dangerous because he can use the `sessionAPPID`. He said that everything is on HTTPS so no one can intercept it...

How can I give him a good Proof Of Concept of what he is doing is unsecure ? I mean beside mentioning the OWASP broken authentication and Insufficient Logging and monitoring I am not aware of any attack that can exploit this (not on portswigger academy at least).

Comment: There are many unclear points in your question. Please explain them. Otherwise it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: 2) Where and how is the header `sessionAPPID` used? Where and how the cookie `sessionAPPID` is used?

Comment: 3) What is the purpose of setting both header `sessionAPPID` and cookie `sessionAPPID`?

Comment: 2- When you send a request (GET or Post...) you need to have the sessionAPPID _a valid one_ in the header otherwise you will be unauthorized @mentallurg

Comment: 3- I also find that weird actually. I don't know why. I need to show that it is also not secure to have it in the cookie @mentallurg

Comment: *"you need to have the sessionAPPID a valid one in the header"* - Then write this to the question. Also write, what side is responsible for setting the header. From the current question it looks like the server sets the header. Also please explain how the client obtains the value for this header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143121/discussion-between-mentallurg-and-rudeus123).

Comment: Plus I said I fond having the sessionAPPID in the cookie weird because he is not comparing it with the sessionAPPID im the custom header... I can put details but more than that it will confuse the reader

Comment: it seems the cookie persists the session... for how long is not clear or if it's rotated... I think the header value is used as an anti-csrf measure.  In that attack the cookie would be sent automatically (the attacker can't steal it, but they don't need to)  If both the cookie and the header are not there the request should not succeed.  The cookie should be checked for the normal security stuff... secure only, http only, same site, etc...

Comment: I believe you've got a session cookie, an anti-csrf cookie, and the custom header bit is the other part of the anti-csrf.  They can both be derived from the session cookie in a way that ensures that only the back-end can decrypt them.  I think the custom header helps keep things secure and same-domain.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the session ID is somehow added as custom header, JavaScript must have access to the session ID. Thus, an XSS vulnerability can exfiltrate the session ID. My suggestion would be to try and find an XSS vulnerability (preferably stored, but reflected works too).

Afterwards, you can log in with the stolen session.

---

All in all, the scheme is not best practice, but it's also not totally busted.

Comment: I think an XSS is a little bit dead because I told him to use angularJS with the user input sanitizer and he did in fact use it ...

Comment: This is a comment. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @mentallurg The question was "How can I write a PoC?" and the answer is "Find an XSS vulnerability to exfiltrate the session data". If you consider this insufficient, please tell me how the answer could be improved.

Comment: *"to try and find an XSS vulnerability"* - this is way too abstract.

Comment: @mentallurg I could say the same about your comment. Would you consider my answer more of an answer if I explained how to find and exploit XSS vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Frittata: 1) My comment is namely comment, no an answer. 2) I'm afraid that the question in its current form cannot be answered at all. The OPs asks about PoC to show that the application is insecure. Insecure from what perspective? Insecure regarding authentication? Insecure regarding XSRF? Insecure regarding XSS? Anything else? I'd suggest you first ask the author to edit the question and clarify all open point, and then answer.